Need help on accessing Druid Portal in internal network
I need help on making druid server accessible inside the local network eg: using local IP: http:192.168.0.1:8888

/var/www/html/druid_local/apache-druid-25.0.0/bin$ sudo ./start-druid


[Tue Jul 30 09:50:34 2024] Starting Apache Druid.


[Tue Jul 30 09:50:34 2024] Open http://localhost:8888/ or http://serverdb-B7M-DS3H:8888/ in your browser to access the web console.


[Tue Jul 30 09:50:34 2024] Or, if you have enabled TLS, use https on port 9088.


Maybe this is solved by setting the druid.host on the router process runtime.properties?
See https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/#static-configuration

I tried out the same but still not working, so just used the Docker Setup which will work fine
